# how to append keys and values from nested dictionaries to lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I build three nested dictionaries to analyze my big data. I try to anylyze values inside them to make a scatter plot, so I am creating a list to append my data to them and then make a scatterplot by matplotlib. My problem is that I get an error while I try to append! TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. so i confused to change structure of my dictionaries or is there possibility to handle it by this from that i have created.

my dictionaries structure are respectively like:

data_geo1:

```
'ENSG00000268358': {'Sample_19-leish_023_v2': 0, 'Sample_4-leish_012_v3': 0, 'Sample_25-leish027_v2': 0, 'Sample_6-leish_015_v3': 0, 'Sample_23-leish026_v2': 1, 'Sample_20-leish_023_v3': 0, 'Sample_18-leish_022_v3': 0, 'Sample_10-leish_017_v3': 0, 'Sample_13-leish_019_v2': 0, 'Sample_1-Leish_011_v2': 0, 'Sample_11-leish_018_v2': 0, 'Sample_3-leish_012_v2': 0, 'Sample_2-leish_011_v3': 0, 'Sample_29-leish032_v2': 0, 'Sample_8-leish_016_v3': 0, 'Sample_28-leish028_v3': 0, 'Sample_27-leish028_v2': 1, 'Sample_26-leish027_v3': 0, 'Sample_12-leish_018_v3': 0, 'Sample_5-leish_015_v2': 0, 'Sample_16-leish_021_v3': 0, 'Sample_21-leish_024_v2': 0, 'Sample_9-leish_017_v2': 0, 'Sample_24-leish026_v3': 1, 'Sample_22-leish_024_v3': 0, 'Sample_14-leish_019_v3': 0, 'Sample_30-leish032_v3': 0, 'Sample_7-leish_016_v2': 0, 'Sample_15-leish_021_v2': 0, 'Sample_17-leish_022_v2': 1}
```

data_ali:

```
{'ENSG00000268358': {'Sample_19-leish_023_v2': 0, 'Sample_16-leish_021_v3': 2, 'Sample_20': 0, 'Sample_24-leish026_v3': 1, 'Sample_6-leish_015_v3': 0, 'Sample_12-leish_018_v3': 0, 'Sample_22-leish_024_v3': 0, 'Sample_23-leish026_v2': 2, 'Sample_25-leish027_v2': 0, 'Sample_18-leish_022_v3': 1, 'Sample_14': 0, 'Sample_2-leish_011_v3': 0, 'Sample_13-leish_019_v2': 0, 'Sample_1-Leish_011_v2': 0, 'Sample_11-leish_018_v2': 0, 'Sample_20-leish_023_v3': 0, 'Sample_3-leish_012_v2': 0, 'Sample_10-leish_017_v3': 1, 'Sample_7': 0, 'Sample_29-leish032_v2': 1, 'Sample_8-leish_016_v3': 0, 'Sample_6': 0, 'Sample_7-leish_016_v2': 0, 'Sample_9': 0, 'Sample_8': 0, 'Sample_27-leish028_v2': 0, 'Sample_26-leish027_v3': 0, 'Sample_5': 1, 'Sample_4': 0, 'Sample_3': 0, 'Sample_19': 0, 'Sample_1': 0, 'Sample_2': 0, 'Sample_9-leish_017_v2': 0, 'Sample_5-leish_015_v2': 0, 'Sample_4-leish_012_v3': 0, 'Sample_21-leish_024_v2': 0, 'Sample_18': 0, 'Sample_13': 0, 'Sample_12': 0, 'Sample_11': 0, 'Sample_10': 1, 'Sample_17': 0, 'Sample_16': 0, 'Sample_15': 1, 'Sample_14-leish_019_v3': 0, 'Sample_30-leish032_v3': 0, 'Sample_28-leish028_v3': 1, 'Sample_15-leish_021_v2': 0, 'Sample_17-leish_022_v2': 0}
```

here is all my code structure from beginning, as you see in the end lines i tried to create list and append my values inside a list but i couldn't successful.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = "/home/ali/Desktop/data/"
root = "/home/ali/Desktop/SAMPLES/"



data_geo1={}
with open(path+"GSE98212_H_DE_genes_count.txt","rt") as fin: #data for sample 1-30
    h = fin.readline()
    sample1 = h.split()
    sample_names = [s.strip('"') for s in sample1[1:31]]
    for l in fin.readlines():
        l = l.strip().split()
        if l:
            gene1= l[0].strip('"')
            data_geo1[gene1] = {}
            for i, x in enumerate(l[1:31]):
                data_geo1[gene1][sample_names[i]] = int(x)

#print(data_geo1)

data_geo2={}
with open (path+"GSE98212_L_DE_genes_count.txt","rt") as fin:
    h= fin.readline()
    sample2=h.split()
    sample_names=sample2[1:21]
    for l in fin.readlines():
        l = l.strip().split()
        if l:
            gene2= l[0].strip()
            data_geo2[gene2]={}
            for i,x in enumerate (l[1:21]):
                data_geo2[gene2][sample_names[i]]= int(x)
#print(data_geo2)

data_ali={}

for sample_name in os.listdir(root):
    with open(os.path.join(root, sample_name, "counts.txt"), "r") as fin:
        for line in fin.readlines():
            gene, reads = line.split()
            reads = int(reads)
            if gene.startswith('ENSG'):
                data_ali.setdefault(gene, {})[sample_name] = reads
        gene = l[0].strip()
#print(data_ali)

list_samples= data_ali[gene].keys()
#print(list_samples)
for sample in list_samples:
    reads_data_ali = []
    for gene in data_ali.keys():
        reads_data_ali.append(data_ali[gene][sample_name])
```

i expect the output like :

```
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [11, 12], [4, 4], [18, 17], [2, 2], [381, 383], [1019, 1020], [198, 194], [66, 65], [2223, 2230], [30, 30], [0, 0], [33, 34], [0, 0], [411, 409], [804, 803], [11829, 7286], [137, 139], [277, 278], [3475, 3482], [5, 5], [2, 1], [70, 70], [48, 48], [234, 232], [121, 120], [928, 925], [220, 159], [165, 165], [702, 700], [1645, 1643], [79, 78], [1064, 1067], [971, 972], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: Why are you expecting such as output? Where are this values in input you've provided?

Comment: You increase your chances for help if you try to break your problem down to minimal example. Furthermore there seems to be some repetitions in your code which is an indication that you can improve the readibility by refactoring (e.g. introduce functions). You might take a look at dict comprehensions as well:  data_geo2[gene2] = {[sample_names[i]]: int(x) for i,x in enumerate(l[1:21])}    Last but not least: your error message seems to indicate an issue with your data set itself. Did you check if accordingly? Used a debugger or at least print? What did it tell you about this case?

Comment: i want to create a numpy array in next step to create scatter plot and compare these values together, these values are numbers in my dictionaries.

Comment: it works well exactly before creating the lists! there is no problem about it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to avoid the keyerror by checking if the key exist in your dictionary before the .append(...). Try to look at the dictionary .get() method. It's good for prevent this type of error.

Comment: it responds when i put one of my keys inside that and it gives me the value! the problem is not about it!

Answer (score 0):

As to your description, I suppose your code of making the dictionaries of `data_ali` and `data_geo1`got the right outputs, so the problem may be in the last code of making a list.
I find two questions:
1 `for gene in data_ali.keys():`, in the following loop, `reads_data_geo1.append(data_geo1[gene1][sample_names])`,here it's `[gene1]`
2`for sample in list_samples:`,so maybe you should use `reads_data_ali.append(data_ali[gene][sample])`
you may revise the name of these variables and see if it works.

Comment: i get the response by editing the first [gene] and then i use [sample_name].

Comment: Happy to know you have fixed the bugs. You're welcome!

Comment: i fixed but it is not the exact one that i am looking for but at least it gives me a response! now i just edit and i hope get the proper one soon :)

Comment: After you revised your code, I see more clearly. I suggest you check two points:

Comment: After you revised your code last night, I got a new question. I suggest you check this point:1. `for sample in list_samples`, when we get the elements, we can't use`data_ali[gene][sample_name]`,  `sample` is a variable,`sample_name`won't be what you want. They are two different variables. Maybe you should revise this part, so the computer will know where to find the element.2.by the way, see if your data type is dictionary,the data you showed in the beginning did not have complete curly bracket pairs. (or Maybe it was a typo. )

Comment: the sample and sample_name is the same variable they are not diffrent from each other! sorry for answering late!